# Independent and dependent variables

Tags: random-variables, independence

Given the following equation:
$$e^{x} \int dz e^{z}$$

If $x$ and $z$ are independent, then: 
$$e^{x} \int dz e^{z}=  \int dz e^{x} e^{z}$$

However, if $x=y-z$, where $y$ and $z$ are independent, am I able to do the following?
$$e^{x} \int dz e^{z}=  \int dz e^{x} e^{z} = \int dz e^{y-z} e^{z} =e^{y} \int dz  = e^{y}z$$

Comment: One idea is to compute the integral $\int e^zdz$ and multiply it by $e^{y-z}$ and compare it to your result. Can that lead you to a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

First, the expression $\int e^z\,dz$ is not uniquely defined as written.  So, let's write instead $\int_{-\infty}^z e^{z'}\,dz'$.

Now, let's look at the expression of interest, $e^x\int_{-\infty}^z e^{z'}\,dz'$ with $x=y-z$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
e^x\int_{-\infty}^z e^{z'}\,dz'&=\int_{-\infty}^z e^xe^{z'}\,dz'\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^z e^{y-z}e^{z'}\,dz'\\\\
&=e^y\int_{-\infty}^z e^{z'-z}\,dz'\\\\
&=e^y \int_{-\infty}^0 e^z\,dz\\\\
&=e^y
\end{align}$$

Note that this is exactly the answer obtained by simply noting that $\int_{-\infty}^z e^{z'}\,dz'=e^z$ so that $e^xe^z=e^{y-z}e^z=e^y$.

Comment: And if, $x = y^2 - z^2$, does it still hold?

Comment: Does what still hold?  If $x=y^2-z^2$, the answer is $e^{y^2-z^2+z}$.

Comment: Instead of $\int_{-\infty}^{z} d\acute{z}$, how does the definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz$ change things for $x=y^2 - z^2$, i.e., $e^x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz e^z$

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^z\,dz$ diverges.